Raspberry Pi Pico Embedded Project: Encoder Interference with Keyboard and Display Integration
Sure, here's your text properly formatted with code blocks:
"I'm working on an embedded project using a Raspberry Pi Pico, which involves creating a keyboard with a 3x3 button layout and a display, along with an encoder to control my computer's volume. When I implement the code solely for the encoder, it functions perfectly. However, when I integrate it with the keyboard and display code, the encoder starts skipping and malfunctioning. Here's an overview of my setup:
Hardware: Raspberry Pi Pico, with an encoder connected to pins GP15, GP14, and GP13 for its two switches and one output.
Software: I've written separate Python scripts for the keyboard, display, and encoder functionality, which I've included below.
Issue: When running the combined code for the keyboard, display, and encoder, the encoder's performance deteriorates, skipping inputs and becoming unresponsive.
I suspect there might be interference between the different components or timing issues in the code.
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
code.py:
import time
import board
import busio
import displayio
import os
import terminalio
import microcontroller
import adafruit_displayio_ssd1306
from adafruit_display_text import label
import rtc
import adafruit_imageload
import digitalio
import usb_hid
from adafruit_hid.keyboard import Keyboard
from adafruit_hid.keycode import Keycode
from adafruit_hid.keyboard_layout_us import KeyboardLayoutUS
from adafruit_hid.consumer_control import ConsumerControl
from adafruit_hid.consumer_control_code import ConsumerControlCode

row_pins = [board.GP4, board.GP5, board.GP6]
col_pins = [board.GP9, board.GP10, board.GP11]

rows = [digitalio.DigitalInOut(pin) for pin in row_pins]
for row in rows:
    row.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
    row.pull = digitalio.Pull.DOWN

cols = [digitalio.DigitalInOut(pin) for pin in col_pins]
for col in cols:
    col.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
    col.pull = digitalio.Pull.UP

keymap = [
    [Keycode.ONE, Keycode.TWO, Keycode.THREE],
    [Keycode.FOUR, Keycode.FIVE, Keycode.SIX],
    [Keycode.SEVEN, Keycode.EIGHT, Keycode.NINE]
]

key_pressed = {}

kbd = Keyboard(usb_hid.devices)
layout = KeyboardLayoutUS(kbd)

def scan_keyboard():
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            cols[j].direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT
            cols[j].value = True
            if rows[i].value:
                if not key_pressed.get((i, j), False):
                    key_pressed[(i, j)] = True
                    cols[j].direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
                    return keymap[i][j]
            else:
                key_pressed[(i, j)] = False
            cols[j].direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
    return None

IMAGE_FILE = "pacman.bmp"
SPRITE_SIZE = (32, 32)
FRAMES = 28

def invert_colors(palette):
    palette[0], palette[1] = palette[1], palette[0]

displayio.release_displays()

sda, scl = board.GP16, board.GP17
i2c = busio.I2C(scl, sda)
display_bus = displayio.I2CDisplay(i2c, device_address=0x3C)
display = adafruit_displayio_ssd1306.SSD1306(display_bus, width=128, height=32)

splash = displayio.Group()
display.show(splash)

temperature_text = label.Label(terminalio.FONT, text="Temp: 0°C", color=0xFFFFFF)
temperature_text.x = 0
temperature_text.y = 25
splash.append(temperature_text)

time_text = label.Label(terminalio.FONT, text="00:00:00", color=0xFFFFFF)
time_text.x = 0
time_text.y = 5
splash.append(time_text)

date_text = label.Label(terminalio.FONT, text="01/01/2000", color=0xFFFFFF)
date_text.x = 0
date_text.y = 15
splash.append(date_text)

icon_bit, icon_pal = adafruit_imageload.load(IMAGE_FILE, bitmap=displayio.Bitmap, palette=displayio.Palette)
invert_colors(icon_pal)

icon_grid = displayio.TileGrid(icon_bit, pixel_shader=icon_pal, width=1, height=1, tile_height=SPRITE_SIZE[1], tile_width=SPRITE_SIZE[0], default_tile=0, x=90, y=0)
splash.append(icon_grid)

rtc_r = rtc.RTC()
pointer = 0

S1_PIN = board.GP15
S2_PIN = board.GP14
KEY_PIN = board.GP13

s1_button = digitalio.DigitalInOut(S1_PIN)
s1_button.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
s1_button.pull = digitalio.Pull.UP

s2_button = digitalio.DigitalInOut(S2_PIN)
s2_button.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
s2_button.pull = digitalio.Pull.UP

key_button = digitalio.DigitalInOut(KEY_PIN)
key_button.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
key_button.pull = digitalio.Pull.UP

cc = ConsumerControl(usb_hid.devices)

def send_key(key):
    cc.send(key)
    time.sleep(0.1)

def update_display():
    temperature = round(microcontroller.cpu.temperature - 5, 1)
    temperature_string = f"{temperature}°C"
    temperature_text.text = "Temp:" + temperature_string

    current_time = rtc_r.datetime
    time_string = "{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(current_time.tm_hour, current_time.tm_min, current_time.tm_sec)
    time_text.text = "Time:" + time_string

    date_string = "{:02d}/{:02d}/{:02d}".format(current_time.tm_mday, current_time.tm_mon, current_time.tm_year % 100)
    date_text.text = "Date:" + date_string

    global pointer
    icon_grid[0] = pointer
    pointer = (pointer + 1) % FRAMES

def check_encoder():
    if not s1_button.value:
        send_key(ConsumerControlCode.VOLUME_DECREMENT)
        while not s1_button.value:
            pass
    if not s2_button.value:
        send_key(ConsumerControlCode.VOLUME_INCREMENT)
        while not s2_button.value:
            pass
    if not key_button.value:
        send_key(ConsumerControlCode.MUTE)
        while not key_button.value:
            pass

oled_update_time = time.monotonic()
encoder_check_time = time.monotonic()

while True:
    current_time = time.monotonic()

    if current_time - oled_update_time >= 0.1:
        update_display()
        oled_update_time = current_time

    if current_time - encoder_check_time >= 0.01:
        check_encoder()
        encoder_check_time = current_time

    key = scan_keyboard()
    if key == Keycode.ONE:
        kbd.send(Keycode.CONTROL, Keycode.ALT, Keycode.P)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        layout.write("https://www.youtube.com/")
        kbd.send(Keycode.ENTER)
    elif key:
        kbd.send(key)

    time.sleep(0.1)




yea i fixed the problem. Here is the solution:if current_time - oled_update_time >= 1:
now = rtc_r.datetime
time_text.text = "{:02}:{:02}:{:02}".format(now.tm_hour, now.tm_min, now.tm_sec)
date_text.text = "{:02}/{:02}/{:04}".format(now.tm_mday, now.tm_mon, now.tm_year)
temperature_text.text = "Temp: {:.1f}°C".format(microcontroller.cpu.temperature)
oled_update_time = current_time
if current_time - frame_update_time >= FRAME_INTERVAL:
    icon_grid[0] = frame
    frame = (frame + 1) % FRAMES
    frame_update_time = current_time

